# Replacing German Umlauts in an ISO 8859-15 file on an UTF 8 system

Tags: python, utf-8, sed, diacritics, iso-8859-15

I have a bunch of CSV files that I read and plot with python and pandas.

To add some more information about the file (or rather, the data it is about) into my plots, I am analyzing their headers, to extract various things from it (location of the measurement point, type of measurement etc.).

Problem is - the files are in German and thus contain a lot of umlauts (ü, ö, ä). Now I can read and understand them perfectly fine, but my script can't.

So I want to simply replace them with their valid 2 character representations (ü=ue, …), so that I dont have to worry about using things like `u'Ümlautstring'` or `\xfcstring` in python.

```
sed -i 's/\ä/ae/g' myfile.csv
```

should do the trick, according to google, but it doesnt work.

With some further resarch, I found the issue, but no solution:

My csv files are encoded in `ISO 8859-15`, but my `locale` is `LANG=de_DE.UTF-8`, which, as far as I understand it, means that sed searches for `ü` in its utf 8 form, which it will not find in ISO 8859-15.

So what do I have to tell sed to find my umlauts?

Most things I have found so far suggest Perl, but that is not really an option.

Comment: The proper solution is to decode the 8859-15 and normalize the resulting Unicode to a suitable format.  `import unicodedata; decoded_normalized = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', open(file, 'r').read().decode('iso-8859-15'))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `LC_*` envvars to prevent sed from doing any UTF-8 interpretation and `\x` escape sequences to specify the umlaut characters by their hex value in ISO-8859-15. Long story short,

```
LC_ALL=C sed 's/\xc4/Ae/g;s/\xd6/Oe/g;s/\xdc/Ue/g;s/\xe4/ae/g;s/\xf6/oe/g;s/\xfc/ue/g;s/\xdf/ss/g' filename
```

should work for all of ÄÖÜäöüß, which I'm guessing are the ones you care about.

Comment: ... until somebody measures something in Angoulême or São Paulo.

Comment: Thank you! That works. But as far as I understand it, that is ONLY going to work for ISO 8859-15 files, and UTF-8 will fail? I guess it would be wise to also look for the files encoding in my python script, so that i can switch to an UTF-8 fallback (or rather, fallup?) should i have such a file?

Comment: Or you could `iconv` everything into UTF-8 before processing.

Comment: @JC_CL You should not let this run on a UTF-8 file, that is correct. If you're unsure of the encoding your file has, use a tool like `recode` to bring it into a known encoding and work with that. (`iconv` requires you to know the source encoding, whereas `recode` guesses it for you). And if you do that anyway, you can forego the special iso8859-15 handling, although you'll still have to know the code points you want to replace and with what to replace them. Or you could make the script work with UTF-8 data.

Comment: @tripleee Good point! Currently I wont need it, but I'll keep it in mind, when I work with international data. Wouldn't it just be simply adding `s/\xe3/a/g;` to the sed line? If I understand it correctly, its just `\x` + `HEX` from [this list](http://www.pjb.com.au/comp/diacritics.html).